# Node use ObjectionJS and Knex, 1 to many, return first related row from the many table

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, knex.js, objection.js

To make things simple, I have two tables for a chatbox: `Conversation` and `Message`

### Conversation

| id | status |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | open |
| 2 | open |

### Message

| idConversation | text | date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 'ffff' | (random date) |
| 1 | 'asdf' | (random date) |
| 1 | '3123123123' | (random date) |
| 2 | 'asdfasdff' | (random date) |
| 2 | 'asdfasdfcas' | (random date) |
| 2 | 'asdfasdfasdf' | (random date) |

I can select all the `Conversation` easily enough by doing:

```
await Conversation.query().where({
    status: 'open',
  })
```

But I am trying to join these together into one query to get 1 message per conversation. This is the query I have for it right now:

```
await Conversation.query()
    .where({
      status: 'open',
    })
    .innerJoin('Message', 'Message.idConversation', 'Conversation.id')
    .distinct('Message.idConversation')
    .select('Message.idConversation', 'Message.text')
```

But this is yielding a result as:

```
  [ 
    {
     idConversation: 1,
     text: 'ffff'
    },
    {
     idConversation: 1,
     text: 'asdf'
    },
    {
     idConversation: 1,
     text: '3123123123'
    },
     ....
  ]
```

I would just like one message per conversation id such as:

```
    {
     idConversation: 1,
     text: 'ffff'
    },
    {
     idConversation: 2,
     text: 'asdfasdff'
    },
```

How could I fix this query?

This is it raw:

```
    SELECT u.id, p.text
    FROM Conversation AS u
    INNER JOIN Message AS p ON p.id = (
      SELECT id
    FROM Message AS p2
    WHERE p2.idConversation = u.id
    LIMIT 1
  )
```

Comment: Sounds like your question is *"How to use `limit` in knex?"*

Comment: That just limits the query to return one Conversation when it should be all where `status = open`

Comment: And which message from each conversation do you want to return, exactly?

Comment: It should be every `Conversation` where `status = open` returned with the `Message.text` of most recent date from the `Message.date` column

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to solve the "max per group" problem.

One way to do this is by correlated subquery, i.e. *"select the message where the date equals (the latest date of all messages in this conversation)"*. This works as long as it's guaranteed by your application that no two messages in the same conversation can have the same date.

In knex this

```
knex({c: 'Conversation'})
    .innerJoin({m: 'Message'}, 'm.idConversation', 'c.id')
    .where({
      'c.status': 'open',
      'm.date': knex('message')
        .where('idConversation', '=', knex.raw('c.id'))
        .max('date')
    })
    .select('m.idConversation', 'm.text')
```

results in SQL like this (note the table aliases)

```
select
  m.idConversation,
  m.text
from
  Conversation as c
  inner join Message as m on m.idConversation = c.id
where
  c.status = 'open'
  and m.date = (select max(date) from message where idConversation = c.id)
```